# Resource recommendation for perturbation theory in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, perturbation-theory

I will be writing a monograph about perturbation theory in quantum mechanics and I need help. My mathematics is not too notch, but I am working on it, plus I haven't finished QM yet, I'm working through Zetilli's book. I am doing bachelor's and I've found some resources but I really need a book that discusses perturbation theory (in QM) in details yet not very difficult to read just so I can get started.

Comment: A lot of people find David Griffiths' textbook beginner friendly, although every standard QM textbook will cover perturbation theory in some detail.

Comment: I would suggest Griffiths' textbook, since it is the standard undergraduate textbook at many institutions, and I think it covers perturbation theory well. There are some online resources that are also helpful, such as this: http://web.mit.edu/6.732/www/new_appendices.pdf